# Elliptic Curve Secret Value Derivation Primitive (ECSVDP-DH) in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, cryptography

I want to derive a secret key using **Elliptic Curve Secret Value Derivation Primitive** (ECSVDP-DH) with Powershell langage using .NET and **NO additional hash function for KDF**.

I have try `ECDiffieHellmanCng.DeriveKeyMaterial` but this method seems to use additionnal KDF with hash function by default and hash algorithm SHA-256 for the output.

[ECDiffieHellmanCng](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> However, instead of exposing the secret agreement directly, the
> ECDiffieHellmanCng class does some post-processing on the agreement
> before providing the value. This post processing is referred to as the
> key derivation function (KDF); you can select which KDF you want to
> use and set its parameters through a set of properties on the instance
> of the Diffie-Hellman object.

I can see this Method `ECDiffieHellmanCng.DeriveSecretAgreementHandle` from `System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellmanCng` namespace but I don't understand how to use this pointer.
[cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.derivesecretagreementhandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.derivesecretagreementhandle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> The DeriveSecretAgreementHandle method overloads are for advanced
> users who need a handle to the raw secret agreement instead of the key
> material. The secret agreement handle can be used in platform invoke
> calls to perform any work that is not wrapped by the
> ECDiffieHellmanCng class.

I search this similar function in .NET
[bouncycastle ECDHBasicAgreement calculateAgreement](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/agreement/ECDHBasicAgreement.html#calculateAgreement(org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters)) or [nodejs elliptic derive()](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic/blob/e71b2d9359c5fe9437fbf46f1f05096de447de57/lib/elliptic/ec/key.js#L102)

I have found also this C++ function which seems to match but I'm looking for an equivalent in .NET
[nf-bcrypt-bcryptsecretagreement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptsecretagreement)

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18610/Elliptic-Curve-Diffie-Hellman-Cryptography) may be useful as far as a .NET example. Apologies if you've already seen it. Someone has a project [here](https://github.com/dahall/vanara) too.

Comment: @Ash, Thanks i will take a look